# Is this a well known sum :$\sum_{p\in \mathbb{p}}{p}^{-\log p}$ for $p$ is a prime number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

I would like to know how do i evaluate  this sum for $p$ a prime number :$\sum_{p\in \mathbb{p}}{p}^{-\log p}$ .

Wolfram alpha show this [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(n%5E(-logn)),n%3D1+to+infty) for $ n\geq 1$ .

**My question is** :Is the above sum for $p$ is prime number well known sum ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: It is $1.020431574796535543347836414414533\ldots$, maybe someone can find it somewhere? For the version with all natural numbers, I find [A099870](https://oeis.org/A099870).